# Why client-side built-in form validation doesn't work if the browser receives the html through http?

Tags: html

I have a server project. Here is a html file. If I open the file from disk directly, built-in client-side form validation works. But if I transmit the file through http, client-side form validation doesn't work. Here is the html file:

```js
async function submitLoginForm() {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
      }),
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      window.location.href = '/dashboard';
    } else if (response.status === 401) {
      const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
      errorMessage.textContent = 'Error: Invalid username or password';
    } else {
      const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
      errorMessage.textContent = 'An error occurred';
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during login:', error);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="loginForm">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required maxlength="10" pattern="^\S+$">
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required maxlength="10" pattern="^\S+$">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="submitLoginForm()">Login</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="location.href='register.html'">Register</button>
  <br>
  <div id="error-message"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the header of http response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2393
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Mon, 18 Dec 2023 00:48:59 GMT
```

I have check develop tool in browser, here is the errors and warnings in console:

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'attribution-reporting'.
> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'run-ad-auction'.
> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'join-ad-interest-group'.
> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.
> An element doesn't have an autocomplete attribute
> A form field has an id or name attribute that the browser's autofill recognizes. However, it doesn't have an autocomplete attribute assigned. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form.
> To fix this issue, provide an autocomplete attribute.
> 1 resource
> Violating node
> Learn more: HTML attribute: autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that the built-in client-side form validation works when you open the HTML file directly from disk suggests that there might be an issue with the HTTP response headers or the way the HTML file is served.

Here are a few things to check:

- Content-Type Header
  Recheck this set correctly to `text/html; charset=utf-8`.
- Then, serve HTML as UTF-8:
  HTML file is saved with the UTF-8 encoding.
- Then, check for additional headers:
- Browser cache:
  You might as well clear your browser cache.
- HTTPS consideration:
  Some modern browsers enforce stricter security policies so you'd better serving your app over HTTPS.
- Autocomplete attribute
  If you check all these, finally, it's good practice to add `autocomplete="off"` to your form fields to prevent browser autofill issues.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required maxlength="10" pattern="^\S+$" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required maxlength="10" pattern="^\S+$" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no other headers. I found if I delete the javascript part, it will work when the html is transmit through http. Does it mean the built-in form validation not compatible with javascript?

Comment: No, you can use javascript to validate built-in form.
Can you replace this ` <button type="button" onclick="submitLoginForm()">Login</button>` into ` <button type="submit" onclick="submitLoginForm()">Login</button>` on your line 10 of html part?

Comment: Tried. still doesn't work. after replacement, it doesn't work even if I open the html file from disk directly.

Comment: By returning `false` at the end of the `submitLoginForm` function, you ensure that the default form submission is prevented. This should help maintain compatibility between the built-in form validation and your JavaScript-based form handling.

Comment: I add `return false;` at the end of `async function submitLoginForm()`, still not working.

Comment: Just as importantly, Did you code this `event.preventDefault();`  before declare the variables like `username` or `password`.

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you so much. There is an error reported by dev tool. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')` Does it matter?